# How to sort from highest to lowest after sum the value in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, eloquent

I am new to Laravel. Right now, I am having a difficulty on how to sort students' name from highest to lowest based on their total marks. Below are my data from the Postman.

```
{ 
  "score": [
    {
        "name": "Adam",
        "sex": "male",
        "totalMarks": 250
    },
    {
        "name": "Lisa",
        "sex": "female",
        "totalMarks": 350
    },
    {
        "name": "Daniel",
        "sex": "male",
        "totalMarks": 300
    },
    {
        "name": "Mary",
        "sex": "female",
        "totalMarks": 330
    },
    {
        "name": "Sarah",
        "sex": "female",
        "totalMarks": 280
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is my code from ScoreController.php

```
$class_id = $user->class->id;
$students = Students::whereIn('class_id', $class_id)->get();
$score = array();

foreach ($students as $student) {
   array_push($score, [
      'name' = $student->name,
      'sex' = $student->sex,
      'totalMarks' = $student->subjects->sum('mark'),
   ]);
}

return response()->json([
  'score' => $score,
]);
```

I would like to sort student based on sum of the `mark`. So a student with a highest `totalMarks` should be at the top of the list. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe `array_multisort(array_column($score,'totalMarks'), SORT_DESC, $score);` will do the trick

Comment: @FelippeDuarte where should I insert that code? Is it inside the `foreach` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using eloquent attributes will probably do you good here. In your Students class add an eloquent [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor).

```
class Students {
    // to include it in the response.
    $with = ['totalMarks'];

    public function getTotalMarksAttribute() {
        return $this->subjects->sum('mark');
    }
}
```

Now you can optimize your original code a bit. You don't have to transform your objects into an array, with this approach.

```
$students = Students::whereIn('class_id', $class_id)
    ->get()
    ->sortByDesc('totalMarks');

// laravel will automatic transform the objects, an way more maintainable approach
return response()->json([
  'score' => $students,
]);
```

Comment: A more optimal route is to do the sorting with SQL, but seeing the original question and where you are now, this approach i suggest is very obtainable :)

Comment: Nice and Laravel-esque!